# In C# how can I prepare a string to be valid for windows directory name

Tags: c#

I am writing a C# program which reads certain tags from files and based on tag values it creates a directory structure.

Now there could be anything in those tags,

If the tag name is not suitable for a directory name I have to prepare it to make it suitable by replacing those characters with anything suitable. So that directory creation does not fail.
I was using following code but I realised this is not enough..

```
path = path.replace("/","-");
path = path.replace("\\","-");
```

please advise what's the best way to do it..

thanks,

Comment: Take a look at [Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getinvalidfilenamechars.aspx) and [Path.GetInvalidPathChars](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getinvalidpathchars.aspx)

Comment: I've got a blog post covering how to write a WPF ValidationRule to validate this very thing, it's got a bunch of code you can rip from it: [*Taking data binding, validation and MVVM to the next level - part 2*](http://techfilth.blogspot.co.nz/2011/07/taking-data-binding-validation-and-mvvm.html). I mention this because there can be a bunch of edge cases when dealing with path and file names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the full list of [invalid characters here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#file_and_directory_names) to handle the replacement as desired.  These are available directly via the [Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getinvalidfilenamechars.aspx) and [Path.GetInvalidPathChars](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getinvalidpathchars.aspx) methods.

Answer (score 6):

Import System.IO namespace and for path use

```
Path.GetInvalidPathChars
```

and for filename use

```
Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars
```

For Eg

```
string filename = "salmnas dlajhdla kjha;dmas'lkasn";

foreach (char c in Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars())
    filename = filename.Replace(System.Char.ToString(c), "");

foreach (char c in Path.GetInvalidPathChars())
    filename = filename.Replace(System.Char.ToString(c), "");
```

Then u can use Path.Combine to add tags to create a path

```
string mypath = Path.Combine(@"C:\", "First_Tag", "Second_Tag"); 

//return C:\First_Tag\Second_Tag
```

Answer (score 2):

The characters you must now use are: `? < > | : \ / * "`

```
    string PathFix(string path)
    {
        List<string> _forbiddenChars = new List<string>();
        _forbiddenChars.Add("?");
        _forbiddenChars.Add("<");
        _forbiddenChars.Add(">");
        _forbiddenChars.Add(":");
        _forbiddenChars.Add("|");
        _forbiddenChars.Add("\\");
        _forbiddenChars.Add("/");
        _forbiddenChars.Add("*");
        _forbiddenChars.Add("\"");

        for (int i = 0; i < _forbiddenChars.Count; i++)
        {
            path = path.Replace(_forbiddenChars[i], "");
        }

        return path;
    }
```

**Tip:** You can't include double-quote (`"`), but you can include 2 quotes (`''`).
In this case:

```
    string PathFix(string path)
    {
        List<string> _forbiddenChars = new List<string>();
        _forbiddenChars.Add("?");
        _forbiddenChars.Add("<");
        _forbiddenChars.Add(">");
        _forbiddenChars.Add(":");
        _forbiddenChars.Add("|");
        _forbiddenChars.Add("\\");
        _forbiddenChars.Add("/");
        _forbiddenChars.Add("*");
        //_forbiddenChars.Add("\""); Do not delete the double-quote character, so we could replace it with 2 quotes (before the return).

        for (int i = 0; i < _forbiddenChars.Count; i++)
        {
            path = path.Replace(_forbiddenChars[i], "");
        }

        path = path.Replace("\"", "''"); //Replacement here
        return path;
    }
```

**You'll of course use only one of those (or combine them to one function with a bool parameter for replacing the quote, if needed)**

Answer (score 1):

The correct [answer of Nikhil Agrawal](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10082286/107625) has some syntax errors.

Just for the reference, here is a compiling version:

```
public static string MakeValidFolderNameSimple(string folderName)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(folderName)) return folderName;

    foreach (var c in System.IO.Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars())
        folderName = folderName.Replace(c.ToString(), string.Empty);

    foreach (var c in System.IO.Path.GetInvalidPathChars())
        folderName = folderName.Replace(c.ToString(), string.Empty);

    return folderName;
}
```